# What is the difference between nuclear charge and ionic charge?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions

There was a question asking why magnesium metal has a higher melting point than sodium.

In the answer, they said:

> - Magnesium has more delocalised electrons.
> - Magnesium ions have a greater positive charge.
> - Magnesium has a greater electrostatic attraction between ions and delocalised electrons.

However, in the mark scheme in the additional guidance, it also said the mark couldn't be given if you said:

> Magnesium ions have a great nuclear charge rather than greater positive charge.

I was confused as to what the difference is.

Comment: What is your weight? Now what is the weight of your _skeleton_? Is there any difference?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77110/discussion-on-question-by-sav-what-is-the-difference-between-nuclear-charge-and).

Answer (score 1):

Nuclear charge is the charge present inside a nucleus, due to the protons. For example, a carbon atom has $+6e$ nuclear charge.

Ionic charge is the charge due to the gain or loss of electrons in the valence shell. So, the sodium ion has an ionic charge of $+1e$ (due to loss of one valence electron). That ion's nuclear charge is still $+11e$ (there are still 11 protons only).

The reason because nuclear charge as an answer to this question is unaccetable is because nuclear charge - being inside the nucleus - has largely no affect on the intermolecular forces between the magnesium atoms. Those magnesium atoms have intermolecular forces governed only by the valence electrons only.